# Unable to call my function in postgresql from java

Tags: java, postgresql, user-defined-functions, plpgsql

```
String sql2 = "{? = call public.insertdepttables('"+stall_be.branchcode+"','"+stall_be.stallcode+"','"+stall_be.nooftables+"')}";
System.out.println("below call"+sql2);
cs = conn.prepareCall(sql2);
cs.registerOutParameter(1,Types.INTEGER);
cs.execute();
```

This code is executing fine. But the table in Postgres is not at all affected.

My function in Postgres is:

```
DECLARE  
count integer=0;
begin
     IF no_dept>0 THEN     
     LOOP
     insert into t_dept(dept_code,branch_code)values(no_dept,branch_code);

     no_dept=no_dept-1; 
     count=count+1;
     EXIT when no_dept =0;
     END LOOP ;
     END IF;
RETURN count;
end
```

Comment: What value is the PostgreSQL function returning? Are you checking it?

Comment: is no_dept > 0 ? and you can return no_dept instead of another counter.

Comment: Your "function" is missing the essential function header. Please supply the complete function. Also missing: Postgres version and table definition.

Answer (score 1):

Much is amiss here.

- There is a good chance the **parameter names** of your function are **conflicting** with column names. But you kept the essential function header a secret.
- I wonder why you schema-qualify your function name **`public`**`.insertdepttables`, but not the table name inside your function: `insert into` **`t_dept`**. What do you get for `SHOW search_path`?
- Also, use [**prepared statements**](http://zetcode.com/db/postgresqljavatutorial/) to pass function parameters instead of concatenated strings to prevent various errors and SQL injection.
- However, there is a good chance you can replace all of this with a **simple `INSERT`** statement using [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html). But again, relevant information is not in the question.